# Google indexed my domain name, but my entity's name with spaces isn't returned

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-index, branding

Working for my client, Google has indexed for some time the index page of my website `example.com`. If a search is done for `"example company"` however, Google returns no results. If the search is done for `"example"`, or `"example company"`, or `example company 314` (part of the business address), Google returns the index page in search results.

I have also noticed examples identical to mine are returned in searches as the first listing.

My code to text ratio is 38%. My maximum number of keyword repetitions in the body text is 5. My description text contains 4 identical keywords, fences. The title text is good. The site is mobile friendly across the website (I used Bootstrap). Page speed is great for desktop about 90+ and mobile about 75+, per google page speed. GTMetrix gives me a 97 and 91 Yslow. The site is optimized as much as it can be and be functional. I can find no place where I am spamming keywords. I Have no doorway redirects or any other prohibited practice. I have a good sitemap.xml file, my robots.txt isn't blocking anything.

Basically, I can't find anything wrong.

Oh, and a P.S., Bing, Yahoo, plus all the other engines bring up the index page with a standard search using the company name.

P.P.S., My domain was purchased from Google domains, I have a Google+ business page, and Google Analytics. Oddly, Google Analytics claims the index page is at position 9.4. Unbelievable.

Comment: A couple of things. There is not such thing as text to code ratio. It is pure B.S. made up by some crazy @$$ SEO. It is a load of cr@p. Secondly, keywords is a myth. Google is a semantics based search engine. Chasing keywords only narrows your search potential. It is all about linguistic semantic scoring. Any apparent term match is simply the highlighting of search terms as the last step of very many and not an indication of how the system actually works.

Comment: As well, searching for westfences.com, westfences, and west fences is a branding issue. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92372/google-has-a-hard-time-finding-organizations-official-page/92379#92379 where I explain some of how this works/is seen.

Comment: @closetnoc: Thanks for your insightful info. Will implement. Strange though, Bing and Yahoo have no problem with a query of West Fences to find the url of the website. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, Bing and Yahoo are the same thing by virtue that Yahoo uses Bings data. Bing and Yahoo have historically been poor and far less sophisticated search engines compared to Google. In fact, Yahoo has failed and is using Bings data which has never really succeeded in well over a decade of trying. That is a shame. Someone needs to compete against Google. Bing is owned by Microsoft which has it's own poor culture and does not see Bing as much of a priority. It is extremely possible to compete with Google within a decade or devastate Bing within 3 years.