# Google ranks for joined words ("foobar") but not separated phrase ("foo bar")

Tags: seo, google, google-ranking

I have a business name containing two words, say Foo and Bar. The name is always stylized as "Foo Bar", but my domain name is foobar.com. The business name is very unique, so I would expect it to rank highly for both "Foo Bar" and "FooBar".

However, I rank #1 for the phrase "FooBar" but cannot get above page 3 for the phrase "Foo Bar". This problem is on Google only, Bing works fine.

**What can I change to rank for the space-separated search phrase?**

[image: Search for "Sweetpricing" has #1 position]

[image: Search for "Sweet Pricing" yields irrelevant results]

Comment: This is a branding issue. This answer explains it all: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92372/google-has-a-hard-time-finding-organizations-official-page/92379#92379

Answer (score 0):

It might take some time until the domain authority reaches a particular level. You might have to create some back links with anchor texts like- "sweet pricing" & "sweetpricing". Try also using internal-linking with anchor texts like that. But Google will take some time to recognize your efforts.
Also try create some other social profiles and link back to your site.