# How can I work around Google's implicit search term splitting feature for a product name?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have a site whose domain and title are the combination of two words. Let's call it `Theproduct` for this discussion. On Bing if a customer searches for Theproduct by name (no space), it shows up as the first result. But on Google, it instead searches for the word split in two (The product) and my page doesn't rank well. The content contains "Theproduct" and "The Product" and several inbound links do, too, from some reputable sites. Google doesn't reveal it is searching for separate words, but if I search for "Theproduct" (in quotes) it returns my page as the first result.

As a result, I am only getting organic search traffic from Bing when people search for the product by name. How can I help Google understand my keyword (the exact product name) shouldn't implicitly separated into two separate search terms when the user searches without quotes?

Comment: This answer will explain a lot of what you need to know. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92372/google-has-a-hard-time-finding-organizations-official-page/92379#92379 The upshot is branding versus term search. Your two terms are not recognized as a brand. That is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google will usually understand that a nospace double keyword like "theProduct" is the same as "the Product". But combining the two words together does change things.

For instance, let's say that your page is about Ford Sports Cars, and the title of your page is FordSports. Because there are not that many pages on the internet with the keyword "FordSports" your page is likely to rank when someone searches for that keyword without the space. There's low competition. But when someone searches for "Ford Sports Cars", there may be many, many pages on the internet about that and so it's less likely to rank.

What this means is that it's very easy to rank your site for a keyword when you combine those keywords together because the competition and search volume is so low. There aren't many pages about and people searching for "theproduct", but there are many people searching for "the product".

By combining the two keywords, it's allowing you to rank when someone searches for it without using a space. Though I'm assuming the search volume for that may be very small.

To help Google understand your page, it's almost always better to use your keywords as intended without the space. A page title of "Ford Sports Cars" is usually better than "FordSports Cars". If you want to rank your page for searches that have the space in between the words, I recommend that you add the spaces into your page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google consider "Theproduct" and "The Product" as Keyword Or Phrase. When we type in search engine
1 - Theproduct (without space)
2 - The product (With Space)
3 - Theproduct.com  (with extension)

These three conditions are different for Google. Here, I will suggest target a keyword or phrase into and outside of your website which really you want to rank.